# Add stroke to Konva shape without increasing its size

Tags: konvajs

When adding a stroke to a Konva polygon (`Line`  with `closed: = true`), half the width of the stroke is added to the size of the polygon.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-kirch-8692q

This is a problem, when there are two touching polygons, since the two strokes overlap.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: The stroke is external to the shape therefore it would naturally add to the overall dimensions of the shape, or polygon in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using `globalCompositeOperation`. An example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/konva-multilayer-214n1).

Answer (score 1):

That is how strokes work in 2d canvas API. The workaround is to make a polygon smaller by half of the stroke size:

```js
const strokeWidth = 5;
const halfStroke = strokeWidth / 2;
const poly1 = new Konva.Line({
  points: [
    10 + halfStroke,
    10 + halfStroke,
    10 + halfStroke,
    50 - halfStroke,
    50 - halfStroke,
    50 - halfStroke,
    50 - halfStroke,
    10 + halfStroke
  ],
  fill: "#00D2FF",
  stroke: "black",
  strokeWidth: 5,
  closed: true
});
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/konva-stroke-9okr6

Comment: Unfortunately, that only works with rectangles, not for any polygon. But, yeah I was afraid that this was a canvas problem.